# Rasterio is masking wrong area?

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, ogr, rasterio

Okay, my goal is to mask a geotiff by means of a shapefile.

Firstly, I made sure that the shapefile and geotiff had same projections:

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr
import gdal
import os


driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
inDataSet = driver.Open(r'shapefile.shp')

# from Layer
inLayer = inDataSet.GetLayer()
spatialRef = inLayer.GetSpatialRef()
# input SpatialReference from Geometry
inFeature = inLayer.GetNextFeature()
geom = inFeature.GetGeometryRef()
inSpatialRef = geom.GetSpatialReference()

raster_path = 'raster.tif'

# output SpatialReference
raster = gdal.Open(raster_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
wktproj = raster.GetProjectionRef()
outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
outSpatialRef.ImportFromWkt(wktproj)



# create the CoordinateTransformation
coordTrans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)


# create the output layer
outputShapefile = r'shapefile_out.sh'
if os.path.exists(outputShapefile):
    driver.DeleteDataSource(outputShapefile)
outDataSet = driver.CreateDataSource(outputShapefile)
outLayer = outDataSet.CreateLayer("GSHHS_f_L1_out_layer", geom_type=ogr.wkbMultiPolygon)


# add fields
inLayerDefn = inLayer.GetLayerDefn()
for i in range(0, inLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
    fieldDefn = inLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i)
    outLayer.CreateField(fieldDefn)

# get the output layer's feature definition
outLayerDefn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()


# loop through the input features
while inFeature:
    # get the input geometry
    geom = inFeature.GetGeometryRef()
    # reproject the geometry
    geom.Transform(coordTrans)
    # create a new feature
    outFeature = ogr.Feature(outLayerDefn)
    # set the geometry and attribute
    outFeature.SetGeometry(geom)
    for i in range(0, outLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
        outFeature.SetField(outLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i).GetNameRef(), inFeature.GetField(i))
    # add the feature to the shapefile
    outLayer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
    # dereference the features and get the next input feature
    outFeature = None
    inFeature = inLayer.GetNextFeature()

# Save and close the shapefiles
inDataSet = None
outDataSet = None
```

Okay, now I use the outputtet shapefile which should have the same projection as raster now to mask:

```
import fiona
import rasterio
import rasterio.mask
import gdal

img_name = 'raster.tif'
shape_name = r'shapefile_out.shp'

raster = gdal.Open(img_name, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
wktproj = raster.GetProjectionRef()

with fiona.open(shape_name, "r") as shapefile:
    geoms = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]


with rasterio.open(img_name, driver='GTiff', crs = 'wktproj') as src:
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, geoms, crop=False, invert=True)
    out_meta = src.meta.copy()


out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                 "height": out_image.shape[1],
                 "width": out_image.shape[2],
                 "transform": out_transform})


with rasterio.open("masked.tif", "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(out_image)
```

But I get this result??

[image]

What's going on?

Comment: How would the desired result look?

Comment: It should have masked the land. As the shapefile consists of coastlines around land.

Comment: I'm using a shapefile with the coastlines of the world. And a sentinel 1 sar image of ocean and part land calibrated into a geotiff in SNAP.

Comment: Is your shapefile Lines or Polygons? It would need to be polygon.

Comment: The problem may be related to passing `crs='wktproj'` to the `rasterio.open` call. Typically you don't need to pass anything here, and if you do it would be a proj4-style dict described at https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/api/rasterio.crs.html .  But `"wktproj"` is not a value that makes sense here.

Comment: I removed the argument but nothing changed :(.

Comment: It's made of polygons.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the quotation marks around the crs - Argument (and only type "crs = wktproj"), as it is a variable and not a string? Looking at your outcome a connection of the problem to the crs seems to be possible to me.